# How to style the help text that appears at the top of pages?

Tags: 7, theming

I'm using the "Piano" theme, and I just don't like the way it displays the help text that would normally appear as a red box when there's an error or a green box for information or to indicate that something processed successfully. I really just want it to be back to normal because right now it's easy to miss and it kind of blends in to the rest of the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `$messages` variable, which is given the following styling by core, yet seems to be removed from that contributed theme:

```
div.status {
  background-color: #f8fff0;
  border-color: #be7;
  color: #234600;
}
div.warning {
  background-color: #fffce5;
  border-color: #ed5;
  color: #840;
}
div.error {
  background-color: #fef5f1;
  border-color: #ed541d;
  color: #8c2e0b;
}
```